# Constructing regular integer matrices with distinct integer eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

How can I construct matrices with positive integer values and distinct integer
 eigenvalues (not necessarily positive, but 0 should not be an eigenvalue). The 
 standard-method to construct matrices with given eigenvalues is a transformation 
 $A\rightarrow B^{-1}AB$, but the problem is that such transformations do not tend to 
 produce positive matrices. A few examples are (the eigenvalues are shown in brackets)

$[4, 2; 3, 5] \ \ \ \ [2, 7]~$

$[2, 5, 2; 5, 2, 6; 6, 6, 5] \ \ \  [-3, -1, 13]~$

$[1, 5, 4, 3; 4, 6, 1, 2; 5, 1, 4, 3; 2, 5, 4, 2] \ \ \  [-3, -1, 4, 13]~$

$[1, 1, 5, 3, 5; 4, 6, 3, 4, 5; 6, 6, 5, 5, 4; 6, 3, 5, 5, 4; 5, 6, 4, 5, 4]   $

$[-3, -1, 1, 2, 22]~$

I do not know a 6x6-matrix or a bigger one with the desired property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a $6 \times 6$ example, try
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 6&1&1&1&1&1\\ 1&6&1&1
&1&1\\ 1&2&5&1&1&1\\ 1&2&2&3&1&2
\\ 1&2&2&1&3&2\\ 1&2&2&1&2&3
\end {array} \right] 
$$
with eigenvalues $1,2,3,4,5,11$.

EDIT:  More generally, start with an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix $D$ with positive integer diagonal entries 
$d_1 > d_2 > \ldots > d_n$.   Let $B$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with first row
$[d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n$ and all else $0$.  Thus $B + D$ is upper triangular
with eigenvalues $2 d_1, d_2, \ldots d_n$ which are distinct positive integers.
Take $A = L (B + D) L^{-1}$ where $L$ is the lower triangular matrix with 
all entries $1$ on and below the main diagonal.  Of course, this has the same eigenvalues as $B+D$.  Note that $L^{-1}$ has 
$1$ on the main diagonal, $-1$ on the diagonal below that, and everything else $0$.  Then 
$$A_{ij} = \cases{d_j - d_{j+1} &  if $ i < j < n$\cr
                  2 d_j - d_{j+1} & if $ i = j < n$\cr
                  2 d_j - 2 d_{j+1} & if $i > j$\cr
                  d_n & if $i < j = n$\cr
                  2 d_n & if $i=j=n$\cr 
    }$$ 
which are all positive integers.

EDIT: Still more generally, you don't need to use the same positive integers in $B$ and $D$...

Comment: Very nice, how did you get it ?

Comment: It even has POSTIVE eigenvalues. I see directly, that 1,2 and 5 are eigenvalues. I checked with PARI, that the others also are.

Comment: Wow! Very instructive. Thank you very much!

Comment: This method allows you to take an arbitrary set of $n$ distinct positive integers, and make them the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ matrix with positive entries.  Nice!

Comment: Not quite, $d_1$ has to be doubled.

Comment: Not if $B,D$ have different values.

Comment: It seems, that there is no nxn-matrix (n>1) with positive integers such that the eigenvalues are the integers 1..n. Can the matrix norm and the spectral theorem be used to find a lower bound for the largest eigenvalue ?