# A positive integer matrix with no integer eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A\in M_n(\mathbb{N})$ with $Tr(A)=0$ and $A^3+A-2I_n=O_n$.Prove that $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $\det(A^2)=\det(A^2+I_n)$.
I tried to find $A$'s eigenvalues, but the equation $x^3+x-2=0$ has only one integer root, $1$,and this contradicts $Tr(A) =0$.
EDIT:My approach doesn' t work as pointed out in the comments, how should this be solved?

Comment: Eigenvalues need not only be integers.

Comment: Why not? The matrix is over $N$. I know that if it were over $C$ it would have eigenvalues.

Comment: The eigenvalues of a matrix with entries in, for instance $\mathbb N$, are solutions to a polynomial equation whose coefficients are in $\mathbb N$. These solutions need not (and in fact are often not) in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I have edited my question, my approach clearly doesn't work.

Comment: I think, $M_n(\Bbb N)$ is a typo.

Comment: No,it is not,this is what the question states.

Comment: It is impossible to have $A^3 + A - 2 I = 0$ and $\text{
Tr}(A) = 0$ if the entries of $A$ are all nonnegative integers.  Note first that if all entries $\ge 0$, any nonzero off-diagonal entries would make the corresponding entries of $A^3 + A - 2 I$ nonzero.  On the other hand, any nonzero diagonal entries would make $\text{Tr}(A) > 0$.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I understand now ! This problem is from a competition in my country,that's why I was reluctant to believe that it has a mistake. However, now I clearly see that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A^3 + A - 2 I = 0$, all eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of the polynomial $x^2 + x - 2$, thus $1$ or $-1/2 \pm \sqrt{7} i/2$.  Since it's a real matrix, the two non-real eigenvalues have equal algebraic multiplicities.  Since the trace (which is the sum of the eigenvalues) must be $0$, 
all three eigenvalues have equal multiplicities.  Thus if this multiplicity is $k$,
there are $3k$ eigenvalues counted by algebraic multiplicity, i.e. $n=3k$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution ! I only have one question : you said this is a real matrix, but the problem states it is a positive integer matrix. Are we still allowed to use the fact that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues? I know that this works only over algebraically closed fields.

Comment: The matrix might have entries in $\mathbb N$, but the eigenvalues are complex numbers.  Yes, this is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Take the matrix in $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &   1   \\ 
 1 &  0  
\end{pmatrix},
$$
it has not integers as eigenvalues, but the golden ratio $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2} $. If you want to construct matrices with integer eigenvalues, then see for example here:

[Constructing regular integer matrices with distinct integer eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858171/constructing-regular-integer-matrices-with-distinct-integer-eigenvalues)